# Display Advanced Custom Fields value in Woocommerce admin order details

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I created an custom field with the ACF plugin to add additional information on the Woocommerce product edit page. It's a subtitle to the product name (all variable products). I was able to make the value appear on the product page front-end and order emails, but I need this information to appear in the admin order details, under the product name. Thanks in advance.

Comment: before to display them in order page, you have to save the subtitle in the order. read my answer there to do that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836452/woocommerce-how-to-add-data-obtained-from-remote-server-to-an-item-after-paymen/58836839#comment103949703_58836839